# How do I pass through variable string to window.open?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, variables, window.open

How do I get the table's information on a specific post to appear in a query window.open? I have tried a few things, but my Jquery skills are not great. This seems possible, but it is eluding me.

```
<table>
    <?php $i=1; foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->dname;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->dateenglish;?> | <?php echo   $retrieved_data->datehebrew;?></td>
        <td><span style="color:#f26522 !important">CLICK CANDLE TO LIGHT</span></td>    
        <td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function MiniCandle () {
                window.open("http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/mini-candle/", "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,left=0,width=260,height=220");
            }
            </script>
            <a href="" onclick="init();"><img height="50" width="50"  src="http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/bootstrap/images/Candle01.gif" class="img-   responsive" alt="Yahrzeit Candle" style="margin:auto !important;"></a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <?php $i=$i+1; } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery here.

Comment: Please be specific what do you mean by "table's information". try posting the error or the result which you want to achieve.

Comment: That's how little I know. Sorry. Umm...

The table is here http://yahrzeit.seanrawles.work when you create a candle it;s supposed to be able to open a pop up to THAT candle with the name created in it.

Comment: The table's $retreived_data from that specific TR.

At the END of the table is the image that pops out the candle. I want that candle to contain THAT ROW's information. I can';t seem to figure it out.

Comment: You see that string `"_blank"` you’re passing? That’s the `name` of the window you’re opening. You can (ab)use that to pass specific information to the new window which you can then read as `window.name`.

Comment: so if I put the variable there it should show up?